# Froala multiple instances on same page - inserts same value meteor-autoform

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform, froala

I use alexche:autoform-froala-editor to add a Rich Text Editor to autoform.

But two instances on same page, insert the same value in different `data-schema-key`. It inserts the String from `structure` in `process`. So it always takes the value from the first Element.

how to avoid this?

Schema:

```
structure: {
    label: "Form A",
    type: String,
    autoform: {
        afFieldInput: {
            type: 'froala',
            inlineMode: false
        }
    }
},
process: {
    label: "Form B",
    type: String,
    autoform: {
        afFieldInput: {
            type: 'froala',
            inlineMode: false
        }
    }
},
```

html:

```
<div class="card">
        <div class="card-content">
            <span class="card-title"></span>
            {{> afQuickField name='desc.structure'}}
        </div>
</div>
<div class="card">
        <div class="card-content">
            <span class="card-title"></span>
            {{> afQuickField name='desc.process'}}
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you inspect the page do the elements that host the Froala editors have the same id ?

Comment: They don't have an id. But they have the same class names.

Comment: ok sorry at the end of my knowledge now.